# Get all items from model (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

```
    $("#collectorscompleted").kendoChart({
        legend: {
            visible: false
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "column"
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Completed",
            data: [@Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID==1), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 2), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 3), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 4),
                   @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 5), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 6), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 7), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 8),
                   @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 9), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 10), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 13), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 14),
                   @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 15), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 16), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 17), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 18)]
        }, {
            name: "Failed",
            data: [@Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID==1), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 2), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 3), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 4),
                   @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 5), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 6), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 7), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 8),
                   @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 9), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 10), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 13), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 14),
                   @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 15), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 16), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 17), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 18)]
        }],
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                visible: false
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18],
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        chartArea: {
            background: "none"
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}",
            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        }
    });
```

I've got the following script. However Categories are now hard typed in myself which is wrong.
My question is: How can I get all `CollectorID`s from the model?

Categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18], // All collectorID's from model here

Comment: Have you tried using `@Model.CollectorIDs` ?

Comment: that wouldn't be possible i gues. I have a model wich contains 3 models. Programstatus, collectorstatus and Datafilestatus. The model Collectorstatus cotains definitions like startdate, enddate, id enz.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MVC. To get the collectorIds from the model, you have to add it to your controller. You have to call you controller in ajax just before calling this initializer. This will looking like this

Javascrit

```
function GetCollectionInformationAjax()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetCollectionInformation", "YourController")",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //call the initialzer here
                Initialize(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

C# your controller

```
public actionResult GetCollectionInformation()
{
    //This is an exemple, you have to replace it!
    return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18];
}
```

Your javascript

```
function Initialize(data)
{
$("#collectorscompleted").kendoChart({
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column"
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Completed",
        data: [@Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID==1), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 2), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 3), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 4),
               @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 5), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 6), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 7), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 8),
               @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 9), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 10), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 13), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 14),
               @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 15), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 16), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 17), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 18)]
    }, {
        name: "Failed",
        data: [@Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID==1), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 2), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 3), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 4),
               @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 5), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 6), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 7), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 8),
               @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 9), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 10), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 13), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 14),
               @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 15), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 16), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 17), @Model.CollectorStatus.Count(c => !c.BatchCompleted.Value && c.CollectorID == 18)]
    }],
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            visible: false
        },
        line: {
            visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: data,
        line: {
            visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    chartArea: {
        background: "none"
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}",
        template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
    }
});}
```